# htaccess redirection to subdomain retaining domain URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to permanently redirect x.com to y.x.com RETAINING the URL x.com

I have a newly redesigned WP website at y.x.com however want visitors to continue to see the x.com address

Im also concerned about retaining the Google juice for x.com seeing that y.x.com is simply a redesign of the original site at x.com

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.x\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://y.x.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
```

so if they go to `http://www.x.com/post/1225` they will see the content located at `http://y.x.com/post/1225`

Comment: Thx - there will be very few pages/posts (if any) that directly match -  can it be edited so that http://www.x.com/anything shows content at http://y.x.com

Comment: It is only rewriting the www.x.com portion and does not care about what is after that, so this will work for anything www.x.com/page.html, www.x.com?p=17 etc

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?x.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.y.x.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking for sub-domain redirection rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.domain.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Replace both instances of "domain.com" with your domain name.